# Fork repository in Bitbucket, keep fork delete original

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have forked a repository in Bitbucket, but I'm wondering what will happen when the original repository is deleted? 
Will the clone also deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, the fork will continue to exist.